# Pygame Rect class unsupported operand types when changing position value

Tags: python

Attempting to move the Rect b1 on the screen to the right when the D key is pressed, however I get a type error when trying to change the x value of the object. I'm sure it has something to do with the child class bug that I tried to create. The application launches and shows the rect on the screen. It crashes as soon as the D key is pressed.

Code:

```
import pygame
print ("Hello world")
pygame.init()
run = True

#Screen
resolutionX = int(1000)
resolutionY = int(1000)
screenColor = (30, 200, 100)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((resolutionX,resolutionY))
screen.fill(screenColor)

#Classes
class bug(pygame.Rect):
    speed = 5
    left = 500
    top = 500
    width = 10
    height = 10
    bugColor = (64,86,102)
    tetrad = (left,top,width,height)

#Objects
b1 = bug

#Main loop
while run:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,b1.bugColor,b1.tetrad)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_d] == True:
            b1.x += 5

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

Terminal:

```
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.12.1)Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.htmlHello worldTraceback (most recent call last):File "c:\Users\Matthew\Desktop#Creek.py", line 35, in <module>b1.x += 5TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'getset_descriptor' and 'int'
```

If I don't use the bug class and instead do this. I get no error.

```
player = pygame.Rect(0,0,10,10)
```

```
if key[pygame.K_d] == True:
```

```
player.x += 5
```

I still like to use a class though for the sake of drawing multiple objects.

Comment: You have to [super init the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods). This is likely to be closed as a dupe though because of the pygame tag...

Comment: "I'm sure it has something to do with the child class bug that I tried to create." - in your own words, **why are you trying to** create a child class? What is your understanding of what classes are, and what their purpose is? What is your understanding of subclassing, and the purpose of doing it? The obvious approach is to **create an instance** of the already existing class. It comes across that you are generally not clear about the distinction between classes and the instances of those classes... ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 There has *got* to be a better duplicate for this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Then try to find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `b1` is a class, not an instance of the `bug` class. When you assign `b1 = bug`, you're essentially assigning the class itself to `b1`, not an instance of the class. To fix this, you need to create an instance of the `bug` class and assign it to `b1`.

```
class bug(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, left, top, width, height, color):
        super().__init__(left, top, width, height)
        self.speed = 5
        self.bugColor = color

# Objects
b1 = bug(500, 500, 10, 10, (64, 86, 102))
```